# Glue for sticking wool to wool?

Tags: material-selection, adhesives, fabric, wool

Can anyone recommend glue for sticking wool to wool? This is for a small, stationary, non-load-bearing, long-term application for an indoor, non-heated environment.

It doesn't need to move around or flex, although it might get slightly jostled or vibrated sometimes.

I would be willing to pay more for something that checks various "hippy" boxes, such as not producing dangerous fumes after setting, not being super-flammable, or being less environmentally destructive or economically exploitative to produce.

Comment: It would help to know more particulars about the application, like exactly what the application is.  Is the wool cloth, felt, batting, etc.?  What safety and environmental concerns are you considering?  For example, any glue used between two pieces of wool won't be exposed to humans unless they eat the wool (is this for infant toys?).  If it's small, there will be a trivial amount of glue unless you're talking about making many of whatever it is.  Are you concerned about fumes from the raw glue before it dries?  How secure does the bond need to be, and will the item be handled/pulled? (cont'd)

Comment: Depending on the application, you might not need glue at all (felting might hold the items together).  Does the result need to be flexible?

Comment: Thanks @fixer1234, I will try to add that information to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most often the best way to stick 2 pieces of fabric together is sewing them. In the special case of wool you can also felt them together by placing both pieces of fabric on a soft foam surface or plush towel and then repeatedly stabbing them with a felting needle. That requires no chemicals at all and you can decide how well they stick together by stabbing them more. You can see [in this article](https://blog.clover-usa.com/2020/02/14/tool-school-needle-felting-tools/) how a red blossom is felted onto a pink scarf.

If in doubt, use transparent construction silicone. It's reasonably cheap, doesn't produce any toxic chemicals (although it stinks of vinegar while curing), and bonds to almost anything almost forever.

It's ideal to put a few tiny blobs of silicone on one piece of wool and then gently push the other cloth into it, but only so far that the silicone bonds to the outer fibres. You don't want to push the silicone through the fibres. If you want to cover a wider area in silicone, use a disposable scraper or plastic object to spread it out. The surface takes only a few minutes to dry, so you might need to split the area into smaller portions. Dip your fingers in some water mixed with dish soap to stop the silicone from sticking to them.

Some alternatives are:

- Plain PVA glue (aka Elmers glue, wood glue, white glue): unbeatably cheap, non-toxic, dries clear, water soluable even after it dries, but may leave stains in the fabric even after drying.
- Acryllic glue (like ModPodge, clear acryllic medium, construction acryllic glue): cheap, non-toxic, somewhat water resistant, but may also leave stains in the fabric.

A word of caution: moths *love* eating wool in a mostly undisturbed indoor environment. The eco-friendly solution is either lavendar blossoms or cedar wood, but you'll have to renew the repellant each year. If you're making something like a collage, try to incorporate a little pocket where you can place the repellant directly into the artwork.

Comment: @capet yesterday I slightly misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to glue **wool** to **wood**. If you want to join 2 pieces of wool together felting or sewing is by far better than glueing them. I updated my answer accordingly. Felting is a hobby enjoied by many kids, so it's not hard at all, just a little time consuming for bigger pieces. If you felt the wool long enough, it becomes virtually inseperable.